# How to remember the selected tab in TabLayout?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

I am using a TabLayout with 3 tabs to show 3 recyclerViews, I am not using ViewPager, so basically I have only one fragment, but when clicking one of the recyclerView's items and going back, the tab's position changes to the first tab. I haven't found much information online when it comes to tabLayout without viewPager, so I don't know how to save the tab position on backPressed

````
class PartnersFragment : Fragment() {
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
 binding.tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
            override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
                if (tab != null) {
                    position = tab.position
                    when (tab.position) {
                        0 -> connectedPartners()
                        1 -> discoverPartners()
                        2 -> rejectedPartners()
                    }
                   
                }
            }

            override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}
            override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {}
        })
} ```
````

Comment: Store the selected tab onSaveInstance and retrieve onCreate

Comment: Even though I do not use a viewPager?